# Set Notepad++ to enable syntax highlighting for files without extensions?

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to set Notepad++ to enable Ruby syntax highlighting via the Style Configuration for a file without an extension, in this case, `Vagrantfile`. Any way to accomplish this?

Note that other editors can read a comment at the top of a file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
```

This may be a good/useful feature for Notepad++!

Comment: You can always load in a file, then manually tell which style to use. Is this enough, or do you always want to have this style applied when a file has no extension?

Comment: It'd be best if it was automatic, of course, but this works too. Updated the OP.